# Modificar campos de formulario de pago de stripe

Tags: php, html5, stripe

Tengo un sitio web en php y voy a agregar la `api` de **stripe** pero veo que el formulario que agrega tiene un solo campo en el cual se escriben los datos de la tarjeta (número, cvv, mes y año) y lo que quiero es separar esos campos para leerlos por separado y poder manejarlo como yo lo tengo en mi sitio web.

La pregunta es, se pueden separar los campos del formulario que integra stripe??

Este es el código html que ponen:

```
<form id="payment-form">
 <div id="card-element"><!--Stripe.js injects the Card Element--></div>
 <button id="submit">
  <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
  <span id="button-text">Pay</span>
 </button>
 <p id="card-error" role="alert"></p>
 <p class="result-message hidden">
   Payment succeeded, see the result in your<a href="" target="_blank">Stripe dashboard.</a> Refresh the page to pay again.
 </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En pocas palabras, la respuesta es no, no se pueden separar los campos. Esto es una limitación intencional, o de lo contrario tendrías que pasar por arduo proceso de certificación con Visa y MasterCard.

Lo ideal es que tu servidor nunca reciba datos de la tarjeta de crédito directamente, sino a través de un token generado por Stripe.

El flujo es el siguiente:

1. Creas un Element en tu formulario (el HTML que mencionaste, mas un poco de JavaScript)
2. Agregas un event listener al botón de "Pagar"
3. Al gatillarse el evento, usas Stripe.js para crear un token que es como un puntero a la información de la tarjeta almacenada de manera segura por Stripe.
4. Usas este token para hacer un form submit en tu servidor, y luego este mismo token para realizar un cargo.

Más detalles [acá](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges#web), con [ejemplos](https://github.com/stripe/elements-examples/#example-1) (ambos en inglés).